# How many orthonormal bases does a disjoint union of orthonormal bases contain?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\mathcal{S}'$ be another basis such that $\mathcal{S}\cap\mathcal{S}'$ is empty and no element of $\mathcal{S}$ is a scalar multiple of an element of $\mathcal{S}'$. Is it true that $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{S}'$ are the only orthonormal bases contained in $\mathcal{S}\cup \mathcal{S}'$?

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't the only one. Your reasoning for not allowing any scalar multiples is presumably to disallow trivial examples where one vector is the negative of another and thus can be freely taken from one base and given to the other. But the exact same effect can be achieved in higher dimensions as well.

For instance, consider $\Bbb R^4$ and the two bases
$$
\mathcal S=\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix}\\
\mathcal S'= \begin{bmatrix}c\\ c\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}c\\ -c\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ c\\ c\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ c\\ -c\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $c=\sqrt{1/2}$ for brevity.

Note that they both consist of an orthonormal basis of the $xy$ plane and an orthonormal basis of the $zw$ plane. These two pairs can be swapped freely, so that we for instance have the orthonormal basis
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ c\\ c\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ c\\ -c\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks, how about we add the following condition: any element of $\mathcal{S}'$ cannot be written as a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{S}$ with fewer than $n$ elements. Would we get uniqueness then?

Comment: @EmilSinclair I though maybe something along the lines of "Apart from the zero space and the full space, there is no space-spanned-by-subsets in common between the two." (The wording needs a little work.) Maybe your requirement is better. At any rate, adding such a requirement will completely change the question. Perhaps make a new post of it? Maybe add in a caveat about avoiding "trivial" examples like this one, and let the comment section duke out what exactly that means?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\mathcal S_1$ and $\mathcal S_2$ are orthonormal bases of $\mathbb R^n$, and suppose that $\mathcal T \subseteq \mathcal S_1 \cup \mathcal S_2$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Clearly $\mathcal T = \mathcal T_1 \cup \mathcal T_2$, where $\mathcal T_i = \mathcal T \cap \mathcal S_i$ for $i=1,2$. Now since it is an orthonormal basis $\text{span}(\mathcal T_1)^{\perp} = \text{span}(\mathcal T_2)$, but in the same way, $\text{span}(\mathcal T_1)^{\perp} = \text{span}(\mathcal S_1 \backslash \mathcal T_1)$, so that $\text{span}(\mathcal T_2) = \text{span}(\mathcal S_1 \backslash \mathcal T_1)$. But if $\mathcal T \notin \{\mathcal S_1,\mathcal S_2\}$, then $\mathcal T_1$ and $\mathcal T_2$ are non-empty proper subsets of $\mathcal S_1$ and $\mathcal S_2$ respectively, hence it follows that any element of $\mathcal T_2\subseteq \mathcal S_2$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\mathcal S_1\backslash \mathcal T_1$, and $|\mathcal S_1\backslash \mathcal T_1|<n$, and similarly any element of $\mathcal S_1\backslash \mathcal T_1$ lies in $\text{span}(\mathcal T_2)$ where $|\mathcal T_2|<n$.

Thus the requirement that no element of $\mathcal S_1$ lie in the span of a proper subset of $\mathcal S_2$ is a sufficient condition for $\mathcal S_1$ and $\mathcal S_2$ to be the only orthonormal bases in $\mathcal S_1\cup\mathcal S_2$, but it is actually not necessary: Let $n=3$ and take $\mathcal S_1 = \{e_1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_2+e_3),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_2-e_3)\}$ and $\mathcal S_2 = \{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1+e_2),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1-e_2),e_3\}$. Then each vector in $\mathcal S_1$ has a nonzero inner product with at least $2$ elements of $\mathcal S_2$ (and vice versa) so that $\mathcal S_1$ and $\mathcal S_2$ are the only orthonormal bases of $\mathbb R^3$ contained in $\mathcal S_1 \cup\mathcal S_2$, but clearly $e_1 \in \mathcal S_1$ lies in the span of $\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1+e_2),\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e_1-e_2)\}$.

The necessary and sufficient condition that follows from the considerations above is the following: If $\mathcal S_1,\mathcal S_2$ are orthonormal bases then they are the only subsets of $\mathcal S_1 \cup\mathcal S_2$ which form orthonormal bases if and only if no proper subset of $\mathcal S_1$ spans the same subspace as a proper subset of $\mathcal S_2$. This condition feels pretty tautological though, so I'm not sure how satisfying it is!